# Graphql records count

Tags: javascript, graphql

I have pretty good understanding of the GraphQl basics but I'm a beginner and as the complexity increases it exposes my lack of overall understanding. I'm trying to get a count of records returned from my resolver and would appreciate any help I can get.

**I have a directory structure like this**

```
graphql
      |
      resolvers
              |
              index.js
              formsResolver.js
      type_defs
              |
              typeDefs.js
```

**The typeDefs.js file**

```
 type UnitSignInForm {
    id: ID!
    givenName: String!
    department: String!
    unit: String!
    isSignedIn: Boolean!
    signedInAt: String
    signedOutAt: String
  }

  #My addition to attempt a separate type for count !!!!!!
  type AllForms {
    forms: [UnitSignInForm]
    count: Int!
  }      

  type Query {
    #The working query to return forms !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    getAllSignInForms(bySignedIn: Boolean, byUnit: String): [UnitSignInForm]
 
    #My attempted implementation of getting count !!!!!!!!!!!!!
    getFormsAndCount(bySignedIn: Boolean, byUnit: String): [AllForms]

  }
```

**The index.js from resolvers folder**

```
     #My attempted modifier
     AllForms: {
       count: (parent) => parent.forms.length,
     },
      Query: {
        ...formsResolver.Query,
      },
```

**Utilizing the working query referenced in the typeDefs.js it returns**

```
{
  "data": {
      {
        "id": "cl4bp1apf0004lkuxhhhxjlyt",
        "givenName": "persons name",
        "department": "MAINT",
        "unit": "some unit",
        "isSignedIn": true,
        "signedInAt": "06/12/2022 12:22 PM"
      },
      {
        "id": "fggfgfgv04lkuxhhhxjlyt",
        "givenName": "other persons name",
        "department": "MAINT",
        "unit": "some unit",
        "isSignedIn": true,
        "signedInAt": "06/12/2022 12:22 PM"
      }
}
```

**My attempt to implement a separate type and count fails but the desired return is**

```
{
  "data": {
      {
        "id": "cl4bp1apf0004lkuxhhhxjlyt",
        "givenName": "persons name",
        "department": "MAINT",
        "unit": "some unit",
        "isSignedIn": true,
        "signedInAt": "06/12/2022 12:22 PM"
      },
      {
        "id": "fggfgfgv04lkuxhhhxjlyt",
        "givenName": "other persons name",
        "department": "MAINT",
        "unit": "some unit",
        "isSignedIn": true,
        "signedInAt": "06/12/2022 12:22 PM"
      },
      "count": 2
}
```

Comment: You probably want `getFormsAndCount(…): AllForms` instead of `getFormsAndCount(…): [AllForms]`.

Comment: Can you show the `getAllSignInForms` and `getFormsAndCount` resolver implementations, please, if that's what is not working?

Comment: Your allegedly "working" query doesn't seem to follow the schema, there's no query that can return this result. Also you can't have values without a key inside an object, did you mean to show an array? Same problem in your "desired" data.